# What is the difference between proper subset and proper superset backwards?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but I don't see the difference between
\begin{equation}
A\subset B
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
B\supset A\;.
\end{equation}
Can anyone explain the difference to me please?

Comment: [No difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#%E2%8A%82_and_%E2%8A%83_symbols): A is a *subset* of B **iff** B is a *superset* of A.

Comment: There is no difference. Sometimes one notation is preferred over the other if the set on the left of the symbol is more important than the other one. (If the text is read from left to right).

Comment: One context where left-to-right order matters is summation notation.  It’s conventional to interpret the variable(s) on the *left* side of the relation in the subscript aa the index of summation.  So you would prefer $A \subset B$ to sum over all subsets $A$ of $B$, but $B \supset A$ to sum over all supersets $B$ of $A$ (though that particular notion needs a bit of refinement in order to make sense)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) $A\supset B$ means the same thing as $B\subset A$, so both things in the original post are the same.

Note that in wikipedia they use notations $\subsetneq$ instead of $\subset$ and $\supsetneq$ instead of $\supset$